# Update data without refreshing the page pug nodejs

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm new to pug, I've read through the documentation and I'm figuring things out as I go.

I have menus that are dynamic, and when the user selects one it needs to load the relevant information into the page.

For example:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3
- Item4

If I click on one of these items it will navigate to 'localhost/item2' or 'localhost/item1', whichever you click on.

I know if I create a route lets say "p" then it will be 'localhost/p/item2' or 'localhost/p/item1', and I can handle all those requests with `p/` and use the `item2` or `item1` to get relevant data

What I would like to do is have a header that wont get updated but a "body" that would change and update on the selected information.

is there a way to do this?

```
//- index.pug
doctype html
html
  include includes/head.pug
  body
    h1 My Site
    p Welcome to my super lame site.
    include includes/foot.pug
```

Is there a way to "reload/refresh" includes without re rendering the page?

I've also thought maybe I could pass the information to the JavaScript page on the server but I only know how to directly communicate with the pug template.

Comment: You should choose to either use pug to render pages server-side or an AJAX library to render them client-side, they are two different paradigms that don't work well together as you will have duplicate presentation logic.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve, then that is exactly what SPAs like Angular, React or VueJS handle for you, so I would highly considering using one.

Nevertheless, under the hood what those Frameworks do is just using jquery to update the DOM accordingly as a response to events either emitted by the frontend or the backend.
If you are going to do this without the help of any framework (I strongly recommend against, your time will be much better used to learn one framework instead of emulating its behaviour), you should have a proper way of comunicating back and forth (ie: [socket.io](https://socket.io/)) and then a corresponding js in the frontend to either informing the backend of actions that happened in the frontend or parsing events from the backend and acting in response.

I hope this helps